# Map stream to list of original indices

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to sort a stream and then collect its elements as their respective original indices.

E.g. for:

```
List<String> l = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "d", "c");
List<Integer> i = l.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> s)).??? // what to do here?
// i = [0, 1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: I guess I could set up a lookup map for the original indices `Elem -> Index`, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way

Comment: Streams don't hold information about the indices. Without instead creating a stream of the *indices* and indexing into the list - which for linked lists would be bad performance, and would be less readable than a for-loop-based solution anyway - there is no way to do it.

Comment: You may first map your elements to a pair of String + index and sort based on Strings. Afterwards you map the elements to just indexes.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-indices

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IntStream`:

```
List<Integer> i = IntStream.range(0,l.size())
        .boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(l::get))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Remember if the list size is larger, then boxed type will be deadly in performance.